# Cypress request with retry

Tags: cypress

In a Cypress test, I need to validate an action by calling an external API.  The API call will always return results (from some prior run), so I can't simply call once and validate the result.  I need to retry some number of times until I find a match for the current run with an overall timeout/failure.  The amount of time necessary to get a current result varies greatly; I can't really just put a crazy long wait before this call.

See comments in snippet below; as soon as I try a request in a loop it's never called.  I got the same result using `cy.wait`.  Nor can I wrap the actual request in another function that returns `Cypress.Promise` or similar, that just pushes the problem up one stack frame.

```javascript
Cypress.Commands.add("verifyExternalAction", (someComparisonValue) => { 

    const options = {
      "url": some_url,
      "auth": { "bearer": some_apikey },
      "headers": { "Accept": "application/json" }
    };

    //// This works fine; we hit the assertion inside then.
    cy.request(options).then((resp) => {
      assert.isTrue(resp.something > someComparisonValue);
    });

    //// We never enter then.
    let retry = 0;
    let foundMatch = false;
    while ((retry < 1) && (!foundMatch)) {
      cy.wait(10000);
      retry++;
      cy.request(options).then((resp) => {
        if (resp.something > someComparisonValue) {
          foundMatch = true;
        }
      });
    }
    assert.isTrue(foundMatch);

});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. You can't mix sync (`while` loop; `assert.isTrue` outside the cy commands...) and async work (cy commands). Read [introduction to cypress #Chains-of-Commands](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#Chains-of-Commands)
2. Your first request is asserting the `resp.something` value and if it fails the whole command fails, thus no more retries.
3. You're doing async work and you can't `await` cypress commands (which you weren't doing, anyway) thus you need *recursion*, not *iteration*. In other words, you can't use
   a `while` loop.

Something likes this should work:

```javascript
Cypress.Commands.add("verifyExternalAction", (someComparisonValue) => {

    const options = {
        "url": some_url,
        "auth": { "bearer": some_apikey },
        "headers": { "Accept": "application/json" }
    };

    let retries = -1;

    function makeRequest () {
        retries++;
        return cy.request(options)
            .then( resp => {
                try {
                    expect( resp.body ).to.be.gt( someComparisonValue );
                } catch ( err ) {

                    if ( retries > 5 ) throw new Error(`retried too many times (${--retries})`)
                    return makeRequest();
                }
                return resp;
            });
    }

    return makeRequest();
});
```

If you don't want cypress to log all the failed expectations during retries, don't use `expect`/`assert` which throws, and do regular comparison (and possibly assert only at the end in a `.then` callback chained to the last `makeRequest()` call).

Comment: Great answer. Thank you!

Comment: This will mix `then` usage with a subsequent `cy.request` which will fail with something like this: `cy.then() failed because you are mixing up async and sync code.

In your callback function you invoked 1 or more cy commands but then returned a synchronous value.

Cypress commands are asynchronous and it doesn't make sense to queue cy commands and yet return a synchronous value.

You likely forgot to properly chain the cy commands using another cy.then().`

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why this works for others but I get same error: you are mixing up async and sync code.

Comment: it's been a while since I was working on this so it's very likely it doesn't work with newer versions of cypress

Comment: If you receive an error indicating that you are mixing async and sync code, try wrapping the result using `cy.wrap`.  For example, instead of `return resp;` try `return cy.wrap(resp);`.  This makes the final result chainable and capable of working within Cypress's asynchronous framework.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach that builds up the Cypress chain to make the call with retries.  If the response isn't found after a given call, it waits a certain amount of time, then tries again.  It does this a configurable number of times with a configurable delay between checks.  At the very end of the chain it asserts whether the match is found.

```javascript
let maxAttempts = 10;
let delay = 5000;
let action = () => cy.request(options)
  .then((resp) => resp.something > someComparisonValue);

let chain = action();
for (let i = 0; i < maxAttempts; i++) {
  chain = chain.then((foundMatch) => {
    if (!foundMatch) {
      cy.wait(delay);
      return action();
    }
  });
}
chain.then((foundMatch) => assert.isTrue(foundMatch));
```

Comment: How come you don't return `foundMatch` from inside the `then` chain? Doesn't this result in the chain mostly being `undefined`?

Comment: Since I'm not doing anything further with the chain after my assertion in my example, it shouldn't matter much what the last one returns.

Comment: Isn't every `then` chained to the last since `chain = chain.then` x retries => `chain.then.then.then`? don't they all use each other's return values?

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you're getting at.  My answer is mirroring the result of the custom command in the original question, which is ultimately just doing `assert.isTrue(foundMatch);` without a return.  My chain here is always returning undefined at the end, since it always ends with this final `assert.isTrue` call, regardless of whether any of the previous values in the chain were `true` or `false`.