# cypress xhr request retry ontimeout

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cypress

I am trying to make the following `XHR` request retry if it times out. If I remove the `cy.wait('@formRequest')`, it seems like the test doesn't stop to wait for the response properly. But if I leave the `cy.wait` in, the test will fail if the request times out. So I tried to add some callbacks (ontimeout) to the `cy.request` call (shown in the second code block), but that doesn't seem to work either. Any idea how I can make this cypress command retry if the response is not 200 OR if a response is not received at all??

I'm pretty new to this, so some explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

```js
// this works, but doesn't handle timeout
Cypress.Commands.add('form_request', (url, formData) => {
  function recursive_request (url, formData, attempt) {
    let xhr
    const maxRetry = 3

    if (attempt > maxRetry) {
      throw new Error(`form_request() max retry reached, ${maxRetry}`)
    }

    if (attempt !== 0) {
      cy.log(`Backing off retry. Attempt: ${attempt}/${maxRetry}.`)
      cy.wait(30000)
    }

    return cy
      .server()
      .route('POST', url)
      .as('formRequest')
      .window()
      .then((win) => {
        xhr = new win.XMLHttpRequest()
        xhr.open('POST', url)
        xhr.send(formData)
      })
      .wait('@formRequest')
      .then((resp) => {
        if (xhr.status !== 200) {
          return recursive_request(url, formData, attempt + 1)
        }

        return resp
      })
  }

  return recursive_request(url, formData, 0)
})
```

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('form_request', (url, formData) => {
  function recursive_request (url, formData, attempt) {
    let xhr
    const maxRetry = 3

    if (attempt > maxRetry) {
      throw new Error(`form_request() max retry reached, ${maxRetry}`)
    }

    if (attempt !== 0) {
      cy.log(`Backing off retry. Attempt: ${attempt}/${maxRetry}.`)
      cy.wait(30000)
    }

    return cy
      .server()
      // .route('POST', url)
      .route({
        'method': 'POST',
        'url': url
      }, {
        ontimeout: (xhr) => {
            return new Cypress.Promise  ((resolve) => {
              resolve(recursive_request(url, formData, attempt + 1))
            })
            
        },
        onreadystatechange: (xhr) => {
          if (xhr.status !== 200 && xhr.readyState === 4) {
            return new Cypress.Promise  ((resolve) => {
              resolve(recursive_request(url, formData, attempt + 1))
            })
          }
        }
      })
      .as('formRequest')
      .window()
      .then((win) => {
        xhr = new win.XMLHttpRequest()
        xhr.open('POST', url)
        xhr.send(formData)
      })
      .wait('@formRequest')
      .then((resp) => {
        if (xhr.status !== 200) {
          return recursive_request(url, formData, attempt + 1)
        }

        return resp
      })
  }

  return recursive_request(url, formData, 0)
})
```

edit:
I tried to make the following custom cypress command. However, I am getting an illegal invocation error. Looking through the documentation on jQuery.ajax(), it's not clear to me what is illegal about it.

I also have a couple questions...
#1. how does passing in the {timeout: 30000} object work? What is this called? My basic understanding of promise chaining is that you pass in some handler function to use whatever the previous call yielded. I have not seen the pattern `.then(arg, function () {...})` before, what is this called?

#2. will cy.log(...) work here? I suspect that it won't because that would be mixing sync/async code, correct? (sorry, I would play with it myself right now but I can't get it to run past the illegal invocation error). Would `const log = Cypress.log(...)` work instead synchronously here?

```
  527 |       }
  528 | 
> 529 |       Cypress.$.ajax({
      |                 ^
  530 |         url,
  531 |         method: 'POST',
  532 |         data: formData,
```

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('form_request', (url, formData) => {
  const waits = { request: 2000, retry: 10000 }
  const maxRetry = 3

  function recursive_request(url, formData, attempt = 0) {

    return new Cypress.Promise((resolve) => {
      if (attempt > maxRetry) {
        throw new Error(`form_request() max retry reached, ${maxRetry}`)
      }

      const retry = (reason) => {
        console.log(`${reason} - retrying in ${waits.retry}`) // #2
        return setTimeout(() => {
          recursive_request(url, formData, attempt + 1)
            .then(data => resolve(data)); // resolve from recursive result
        }, waits.retry)
      }

      Cypress.$.ajax({
        url,
        method: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        timeout: waits.request,
      })
        .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          if (textStatus !== 'success') {
            retry('Status not success')
          }
          resolve(data)
        })
        .catch(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          retry(errorThrown)
        })
    })
  }

  cy.wrap(null)
    .then({ timeout: 30000 }, // #1
      () => {
        return recursive_request(url, formData)
      })
    .then((result) => {
      return result
    })
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54081260/1727948

Comment: Try moving the ontimeout callback to the `xhr` object, see [XMLHttpRequest: timeout event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/timeout_event)

Comment: @konekoya , unfortunately not since i'm trying to handle the case where there is no response to speak of.

Comment: @Ackroydd so i can try something like this, and I need to remove the cy.wait('@formRequest') , but now it does not run in the order expected (ie. it does not seem to wait anymore before executing the chained .then) and im dont think that the xhr.ontimeout = () => {...} will ever get run in this case.

Comment: I think you definitely need the `cy.wait('@formRequest')`. The trick is to not fail until `attempt > maxRetry` - but unfortunately the xhr timeout event is not cancelable - so I don't using `ontimeout` will work.

Comment: You could `.wait(..., { timeout: some-really-high-timeout })` then implement your own non-failing-but-recursing timeout with `setTimeout()`. Maybe the trick is not to use `cy.route()` at all. Just handle the xhr recursively and write an `expect()` on the return value of `recursive_request`.

Comment: @Ackroydd that's an interesting suggestion that I Havent thought of. To the best of my knowledge, if the `cy.wait` never resolves (eg. due to the really high timeout), then subsequent cy commands will not run? Since I thought that cypress commands go through and enqueue everything to be run sequentially? Or is that not the case?

Comment: No, the wait should pass if one of the retries succeeds just as with a normal (non-retrying) `.route()`. Otherwise, your thrown error should fail the test (and there's no need for the wait to pass).

Comment: Hmmm, not sure I quite understand you just yet. Let me think a bit about it. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Your data is not formData as code implies. Set `contentType: false` - ***contentType (default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8') ... pass false to tell jQuery to not set any content type header***. Also `processData: false` - ***processData (default: true), If you want to send ... other non-processed data, set this option to false.***.

Comment: ah! that solved the illegal invocation problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Test-level retries**

I would take a look at [test-retries](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/test-retries.html#Custom-Configurations) (Cypress v 5.0+) to handle the timeout issue,

```js
const waitTime = 1000; // shortened for demo 

Cypress.Commands.add('form_request', (url, formData) => {

  return cy
    .request({
      method: 'POST', 
      url,
      body: formData,
      timeout: waitTime
    })
    .then((resp) => {
      if (resp.status !== 200) {
        throw new Error(`Status not 200`)
      }
      return resp
    })
})

let attempts = 0;

it('repeats', { retries: 3 }, () => {

  const wait = attempts ? waitTime : 0;  // initial wait = 0
  const url = attempts < 2
    ? 'http://nothing'                   // initially use a non-reachable url
    : 'http://example.com';              // 3rd attempt succeeds
  attempts++;
  cy.wait(wait).form_request(url, { name: 'Fred' })

})
```

---

**Request-level retries**

If you want to retry at the request level (not the test level), then @Ackroydd is correct - you should ditch the `cy.route()` because, in short, Cypress commands are not built to catch fails.

Here is a basic example using `jquery.ajax`. You may get a more succinct function using something like [axios.retry](https://github.com/softonic/axios-retry).

Refer to [Waiting for promises](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/promise.html#Waiting-for-Promises) for the Cypress pattern used.

**Recursive request**

```js
const waits = { request: 2000, retry: 10000 } 
const maxRetry = 3

function recursive_request(url, formData, attempt = 0) {

  return new Cypress.Promise ((resolve) => {
    if (attempt > maxRetry) {
      throw new Error(`form_request() max retry reached, ${maxRetry}`)
    }
  
    const retry = (reason) => {
      console.log(`${reason} - retrying in ${waits.retry}`);
      return setTimeout(() => {
        recursive_request(url, formData, attempt + 1)
          .then(data => resolve(data)); // resolve from recursive result
      }, waits.retry)
    }
    
    Cypress.$.ajax({
      url,
      method: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      timeout: waits.request,
    })
    .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      if (textStatus !== 'success') {
        retry('Status not success')
      }
      resolve(data)
    })
    .catch(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      retry(errorThrown)
    })
  })
}
```

**Test**

```js
it('retries form post', () => {

  cy.wrap(null)
    .then(
      { timeout: 30000 },   // timeout must be above maximum expected, 
                            // i.e maxRetry * waits.retry
      () => recursive_request('http://localhost:3000', { name: 'Fred' })
    )
    .then(result => console.log(result))

})
```

**Flaky server used to test**

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const obj = {
  name: 'Fred'
};

let attempt = 0;

app.post("*", (req, res) => {
  if (attempt >= 3) {
    attempt = 0;   // reset to allow multiple test runs
    res.status(201).json(obj)
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Comment: hey Richard, thanks for your response! Using test retries seems like a good idea, and I'm guessing that with your suggestion, you're not aware of any way to handle retries within the cypress command itself? 

the reason i ask is that the form_request is used to send blobs as part of a longer end to end test. I could isolate that portion of the test execution where form_request is called as a new test, but would prefer not to (if possible). As to having the entire test repeat - it's possible but leads to other problems (backend resources being hammered, prefer to only retry where necessary)

Comment: hi Richard, wow thank you for the very detailed code. I will study your answer and try it out to see if it works. Thank you again!

Comment: hi Richard, I have tried to adapt your comments to fit into one custom cypress command. Reason being that `cy.form_request(...)` is called to send a blob to the endpoint. I also have some additional questions about the code you provided, thank you so much for your time! I am learning so much about how this stuff works. (i have edited the main original question)