# How can I retry cy.request in cypress with delay, and retry limit

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to achieve something similar to [Cypress request with retry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54079106/cypress-request-with-retry) - although comments on that post suggest the solution no longer works / never did work?!

Anyway, I need to send a request to an elastic server, and if no records are returned, wait a bit, then try again (retrying every few (10) seconds, up to say, 2 mins of retries at most)... ie something like:

```
cy.request({auth,method,body,url...}).then(reqresult => {
  if (reqresult.body.hits.hits.length){
    // results are in elastic, return them
  }
  else {
    cy.wait(10000)
    // repeat the request, if retry attempts not exceeded, or return the empty response if exceeded
  }
})
```

But everything I've tried (including similar to the post above) has either produced the "mixing async with sync" error, or has simply looped without resending the request, or at worst, has caused my Cypress (10.3.0) window to hang completely!

Can anyone offer any help please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for [Request Polling](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request#Request-Polling)?

```js
function req (retries = 0) {

  if (retries > 10) throw new Error('Request failed');   // for limit

  cy.request(...)
    .then((resp) => {
      // if we got what we wanted

      if (resp.status === 200 && resp.body.ok === true)
        // break out of the recursive loop
        return

      // else recurse
      cy.wait(10000)            // for delay
        .then(() => req())      // queue the next call
    })
}

req()   // initial call
```

Comment: Mistake in original - need to `.then()` the next call.

Comment: May need to set `failOnStatusCode` to false to get more retries in.

Comment: That looks sooo much like at least something I tried.... the key difference being the above seems to work! :) Thanks @Fody

Comment: You're welcome. The hardest part IMO is figuring out how to call the next recursion.

Comment: retries is not incremented, therefore to fix after n retries, pass `retries + 1` in the queing call:  `.then(() => req(retries + 1))`